# How should I create subtypes of Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

How can I create multiple types that are essentially Ints, i.e can get the int value, can use math operators like + BUT where instances of different types can not be mixed.

For example:

```scala
val density1 = new Density(100)
val density2 = new Density(200)
density1 + density2 should be(new Density(300))

val variability = new Variability(1)
variability.value should be(1)
density1 + variability // does not compile
```

There could be hundreds of these types and I do not want to have to implement operators like + in each leaf class.

Ideally, I would like to avoid all implicit conversion mechanisms (personal preference only). Additional types should not require altering existing types.

Comment: Why not just to create a wrapper over Int?

Comment: Scala 3 is getting [opaque types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/opaque-types.html) for this use case. That page describes the Scala 2 alternatives.

Comment: @AminMal As I understand the question is _how_ to create a wrapper over `Int` given "There could be hundreds of these types and I do not want to have to implement operators like + in each leaf class"

Comment: I did try creating a wrapper.  The problem becomes how to mix in the math operators.  There may be a way to extract the operators by trait, e.g. Addable but the construction of a new instance in that trait of a unknown type becomes problematic.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt opaque types look like the scalable solution to this and I can move to Scala 3.

Comment: It turns out that opaque types (though very useful) do not fit my use case.  The main problem is that there does not seem to be a way to allow multiple opaque types to share common arithmetic operations like +.  Each operation must be repeated in the companion object of each opaque type.  So I think value classes remain my best option.

Comment: @DuncanGreen Multiple opaque types can share methods like `+` (as my answer shows). I'm not sure what you mean when you say each operation must be repeated in the companion object of each opaque type. Do you mean the extension when you say companion object? There's only one collective extension that can be used for all the methods.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in Scala 3 that I don't think uses boxing/unboxing:

```scala
object Wrappers:
  opaque type Wrapper = Int
  
  extension[T <: Wrapper](t: T)(using util.NotGiven[T =:= Wrapper]):
    def +(other: T): T = (t + other).asInstanceOf[T]
    //other methods
  
  opaque type Density <: Wrapper = Int
  def Density(i: Int): Density = i
  
  opaque type Variability <: Wrapper = Int
  def Variability(i: Int): Variability = i
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6eO76efNSkSG2zJ2vHYXCw)

Testing:

```
val density1 = Density(1)
val density2 = Density(2)
val density3: Density = density1 + density2    //compiles

val check1: Variability = density1 + density2  //doesn't compile

val variability = Variability(1)
val check2 = (variability: Wrapper) + density2 //doesn't compile
val check3 = variability + density2            //doesn't compile

println(density1) //1
println(density2) //2
println(density3) //3
```

The `asInstanceOf` is unchecked and shouldn't affect performance. This design *should* also keep the `Int`s from being boxed, but I can't guarantee that, and it also depends on how you use this. Another nice thing about this is that every new type requires only 2 more lines of code. And to make adding new methods easier, you can probably also make a new method of your own to shorten `asInstanceOf[T]`.

Comment: This looks interesting but would prefer not to use reflection for performance and Liskov compliance.  Odersky says you can "recover type information" through pattern matching but it's unclear how to close those match statements against new types.

Comment: I think opaque types look like the scalable way to solve this problem.  Is there a way to avoid the instanceof?

Comment: @DuncanGreen `.asInstanceOf[T]` has no performance penalty in this case. It's also quite safe since it's incapsulated in a module. So no external users would need to call `instanceOf` themselves.

Comment: @DuncanGreen There's no reflection here, and with the addition of the `Matchable` trait, you can't pattern match on opaque types and find out they're all really `Int`s. So I think it is a rather safe approach.

Comment: Ok thanks.  It looks like a clear violation of Liskov Substitution Principal to me. :)

Comment: @DuncanGreen I don't understand how, could you explain? (I vaguely remember LSP being something about subclasses behaving like superclasses, but my memory's a little fuzzy on that). Still, if you're worried about the real nature of `Density` and `Variability` leaking through, that'll only happen if people use `asInstanceOf[Int]` or something like that, which they probably shouldn't be doing anyways. Pattern matching (probably) won't be a problem in Scala 3 (see [this SIP](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/add-matchable-trait/4699)).

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/?LiskovSubstitutionPrinciple

I think your solution maybe comparitively safe though because I don't see how (t + other) could resolve to anything other than T.  In general 'downcasting' from a base type to a more specific type violates Liskov but I don't think you are doing that in this case.  So all good!

Comment: Found an issue with this approach though.  The following ought not to compile as I do not want to mix these types with each other.
val density = Density(1); 
val variability = Variability(2); 
density + variability should be(3);  // ought not to compile.

Comment: I see my problem. I am having trouble getting (using util.Not[T =:= Wrapper]) to compile. I get 'Cyclic reference involving implicit value x$1'.  Without that clause types can be mixed.

Comment: Fixed it. util.Not is now called util.NotGiven in scala 3. https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/change-the-name-for-scala-util-not-to-scala-util-notgiven/4673

Comment: @DuncanGreen Great! I've also changed that in my answer (although the Scastie link still has to use `Not` - if I use `NotGiven` there's an error).

Answer (score 2):

```
trait TaggedInt[T <: TaggedInt[T]] {
  val value: Int
  protected def apply(value: Int): T
  def +(other: T) = apply(value + other.value)
  // etc.
}

case class Density(value: Int) extends TaggedInt[Density] {
  override protected def apply(value: Int) = Density(value)
}
```

> I was desperately trying to get around having to repeat `override protected def apply(value: Int) = ...` all the time

You can make it a constructor parameter then. Slightly less efficient but probably won't matter in practice:

```
abstract class TaggedInt[T <: TaggedInt[T]](constructor: Int => T) {
  val value: Int
  def +(other: T) = constructor(value + other.value)
  // etc.
}

case class Density(value: Int) extends TaggedInt[Density](Density)
```

I originally had

```
case class TaggedInt[Tag](value: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: TaggedInt[Tag]) = TaggedInt[Tag](value + other.value)
  // etc.
}

trait DensityTag
type Density = TaggedInt[DensityTag]

trait VariabilityTag
type Variability = TaggedInt[VariabilityTag]
```

but it has at least 2 problems for this usecase:

1. `Density(100).toString` is `TaggedInt(100)` instead of `Density(100)`;
2. `Density(100)` is equal to `Variability(100)`.

Comment: I came up with the same thing but I was desperately trying to get around having to repeat `override protected def apply(value: Int) = ...` all the time

Comment: This is pretty much verbatim what I currently have.  Thanks for pointing out the limitations.  Initially it looks like a simple matter of wrapping int by inheriting from AnyVal but that blocks further inheritance and, to be honest, seems rather cumbersome.